# How do I set the public and private key on RSAParameters to use for RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I read some tutorials online, and generated a public and private key, but how do I set them to be used in C#?  Here is what I have:

```
        string publicKey = "...";
        string privateKey = "....";
        UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("Data to Encrypt");
        byte[] encryptedData;
        byte[] decryptedData;
        string decrptedStr = "";
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
            RSAParameters myRSAParameters = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
            myRSAParameters.Modulus = ByteConverter.GetBytes(publicKey);
            myRSAParameters.Exponent = ByteConverter.GetBytes(privateKey);
            encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, myRSAParameters, false);
            decryptedData = RSADecrypt(encryptedData, myRSAParameters, false);
            decrptedStr = ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData);
        }
```

Here are the encrypt / decrypt function that I copied strait from M$ website:

```
    static public byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding) {
        try {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
                encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        } catch (CryptographicException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

            return null;
        }

    }

    static public byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo, bool DoOAEPPadding) {
        try {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        } catch (CryptographicException e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems here. You don't indicate the encoding of your public/private keys, but I can be sure that regardless of the encoding, simply getting the byte equivalent of the Unicode encoded string via `ByteConverter.GetBytes(...)` is not going to work. These should be the byte-array equivalent of the numeric RSA parameters.

The second problem is your interpretation of the "public" and "private" keys. The public key is not (just) the modulus, and the private key is not the exponent. The public key is comprised of the modulus *and* the (public) exponent (the `Exponent` property of the `RSAParameters` type, and the private key is the modulus and the *private* exponent (the `D` property of the `RSAParameters` type). However, in order to be used for decryption, the `RSAParameters` imported into the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` must also have the `DP`, `DQ` and `InverseQ` properties set (`P` and `Q` may also be required though I've not tested this).

Again, without knowing the encoding used in your public/private keys, I can't give any further details as to how to extract the appropriate values for populating the necessary properties of `RSAParameters`.

Comment: Well said, Iridium. Having the public/private exponent and modulus is enough to perform RSA. The other parameters are useful if you want to speed up the private key operations using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: This is old of course - but there's another possible problem: creating myRSAParameters using an RSACryptoServiceProvider object's ExportParameters, the result has all fields set to some values. Overwriting *some* of them with new data will create a data set with inconsistent data. Better create a new RSAParameters.