# How can I load a RSA public key in C# and use it to encrypt something?

Tags: c#, python-2.7, rsa, public-key-encryption, public-key

I made a simple script which load the RSA public key to encrypt a string in Python :
(P.S. I'm using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) RSA library)

```
import rsa
rsa_key = "81474a6ab9a4b69aad47d8674e1de67130dd004eb532dcce7c1fc874e0b078ad2eeb88ae72066d018ad614e18f8e2d411e6ac0f483fb7b6877fe814583dfea02056f04db34185bc7ecfe31ef2297e5f282575300c3f7497823ace8e6240e6f611cf3b4c8bfabf9e4092dd00dc66d5fa35cdb14f3f0bcff2c6c0c9b4ecc3aea2822583fef359200580e8495a152e7cb7aca4de7da719f"
e = "10001"
pub_key = rsa.PublicKey(int(rsa_key,16), int(e,16))
crypto = rsa.encrypt("message", pub_key).encode("hex")
```

So how can I do the same thing in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RSACryptoServiceProvider from System.Security.Cryptography.

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

byte[] data = enc.GetBytes("message");
byte[] encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(data, true);
byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(encrypted, true);

Console.WriteLine(enc.GetString(decrypted));
```

For more info and an example setting the public key:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b50472-b23f-4191-b8f4-e4a696fca5e4/how-to-use-a-public-key-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider-class?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685939/how-do-i-set-the-public-and-private-key-on-rsaparameters-to-use-for-rsacryptoser can help?